# How to fix 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' error in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have tried a code to calculate distance of moving objects using video feed with two web cameras. I have got this error

> 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

when I run the code. How can I fix it?

```
def next(self,black=True,wait=0):
    # black frame default
    if black:
        frame = self.black_frame

    # no frame default
    else:
        frame = None

    # get from buffer (fail if empty)
    try:
        frame = self.buffer.get(timeout=wait)
        self.frames_returned += 1
    except queue.Empty:
        print('Queue Empty!')
        #print(traceback.format_exc())
        pass

    # done
    return frame
```

Comment: The `buffer` is none.

Comment: Your `self.buffer` is None

Comment: We will need to see how you are creating `self.buffer`. Are you setting it to be `None` by default? Are you accidentally setting it to be the output of an in-place function like `list.append()`?

Comment: What part of error you didn't understand?

Comment: @C.Nivs This is my full code. [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gcszdf2j-S49_njeAtkiWZNUtN7D9DOw)

Comment: @ChamaliNirashaPremarathna it looks like it's an issue with `self.stop` which explicitly sets `self.buffer` to `None`. Are you calling `loop` on the `Frame` object and then acting upon it later? Because `loop` calls `stop`, which would cause that issue. It might be better to set `buffer` to be empty, rather than `None`. Or, explicitly check `is not None`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting explains it all,

```
     frame = self.buffer.get(timeout=wait)
```

Buffer is none, either you are not defining it in the constructor or somewhere before this function you are setting it to `None`

Comment: I don't think this answer is of any help. It is more of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

you could just add an if else block :

```
if self.buffer: # This will test if the buffer is not None
    # Do access the get method. 
else: 
    # Say buffer is None or do something else.
```

More explicitly  :

```
if self.buffer is not None:
    # Do access the get method. 
else: 
    # Say buffer is None or do something else.
```